# PageProgress команда в JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp

Доброго дня!

Вызываю модальное окно

```html
function OnGetRowValues(r) {

    pcMeasurementsChoiceMSQQ.SetContentUrl('PageProgress.aspx?Page=Passport/FormMSQQ_MI.aspx?pos=' + hfWR.Get("PosID") + ';id_measurement=');
    pcMeasurementsChoiceMSQQ.Show();
}
```

Окно это действительно существует в проекте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выходит сообщение-ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём же дело?

Comment: Читайте внимательно ошибку Страница то у вас есть, да вот путь к ней другой (забыли про папку Passport)

Comment: Так папка Passport присутствует в пути. Вот загвоздка. Правильно же прописал? 'PageProgress.aspx?Page=Passport/FormMSQQ_MI.aspx?pos='

Comment: Вы обращаетесь к странице 'PageProgress.aspx` У неё какой путь? И что написано в сообщении об ошибке, там где запрашиваемый урл? Оно совпадает?

Comment: Видно же по моим скринам,что совпадает. Разве нет?

Comment: Я говорю про страницу `PageProgress.aspx`. По урл из ошибки она запрошена из папки `CardFileMSQQ`, но по скрину из вопроса в папке `CardFileMSQQ` нет файла `PageProgress.aspx`

Comment: Это же команда так называется, PageProgress, когда находишься на странице открытой и с неё прыгаешь на другую, нет? У меня в проекте этот PageProgress повсюду используется...Вот загвоздка.

Comment: Команда кому? `PageProgress.aspx` - это страница где то на сервере и вы её запрашиваете с какими то параметрами.

Comment: Теперь понял. Спасибо большое!! Добавил эту страницу в каталог, всё заработало.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Рад, что помогло. Но вообще, вместо копирования страницы, лучше указать правильный путь к ней.